# Mac: I can su but not authorize as admin

Tags: macos, mac

Having a bizarre problem on my Mac and was hoping you guys could help.

My main user that I use every day is no longer allowed superuser privileges in the GUI. For instance, if you go to System Preferences/Accounts and 'Click the lock to make changes' it will always reject the password I enter with the message 'Try entering your information again.' and an 'OK' button.

I figured that the user had dropped out of the admin group but that is not the case. When I use 'groups' you can see that it is clearly there. I also have no problems using su & sudo from the command line. When you check the user with dscl it is still in the admin group.

I added another admin user from the command line using dscl and used that to remove and then re-add admin privileges from my main user but that didn't work.

I've also tried running Disk Utility and Repair Permissions but that hasn't worked either.

Am running a MacBook (early '09) with the latest version of Snow Leopard (10.6.2)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an issue that looks the same and I finally figured out my problem.

I had been using `dscl` (Directory Services Command Line utility) to setup groups and accounts for an Oracle software installation on my Mac.  I then tried putting myself into the same group as the owner of the software.  Not knowing what I was doing, I inadvertently assigned more than one `PrimaryGroupID` to my user account.

Somehow that prevented me from doing admin tasks, even though I was a member of the `admin` group.  What clued me in on the problem was the word "primary" in `PrimaryGroupID` ("primary" implies "one").  So after removing the extra `PrimaryGroupID` assignment from my user account, I could resume admin operations on my Mac.

Comment: This sounds exactly the problem. I've just done an oracle install and have just been messing about with the pids. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, you hit the nail squarely on its head. Shame on those who voted down this answer.

Comment: Look at the edit history. It seems he initially posted "Did you ever figure out your problem? I seem to be having the same issue here.", and then updated it when he solved his problem.

The "Me Too" Answer is what got voted down.

Comment: @Fake Name: correct.  it's possible (and encouraged!) that the downvoters will remove their downvotes (or even change them to upvotes!) now that he's edited it into a real answer.

Comment: They oughta upvote you for your effort @~quack ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be part of the *staff* group.

- When you go to System Preferences -> Accounts -> unlock preferences if needed -> right clic on your account -> select "Advanced Options" :

Are still member of the *staff* group ?

- When you go to System Preferences -> Accounts -> click on your account :

Is there a tick in the box "Allow to administer the computer" ?

- When the box to authenticate yourself appears, is the full name correct ?
- Did you change your username/full name recently ?
- Try to authenticate with your username instead of your full name when this box appears.